# mex file run out of memory

Tags: matlab, memory-management

I wrote a mexfunction on c++ code, then compiled it to get mexa64 file. After I used mexa64 file for many times, my PC memory run out.

Here is my mexfunction:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
//  double *res ;// the final result index 
    int status1,status2,status3;
    double *res ;
    double *out_mat;
    double *x_idx,*y_idx,*width_idx,*height_idx;
    char* sequence_path;// the tracking image sequences
    char* sequence_name;// the tracking image sequences


    char* output_path;// save the output    
    int start_frame=(int)mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
    int end_frame=(int)mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
    int Max_track_number=(int)mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);     

     /* Extract the inputs */   
    int buflen1=(mxGetM(prhs[3])*mxGetN(prhs[3]))+1;
    sequence_path= (char *)mxCalloc(buflen1,sizeof(char));   
    status1=mxGetString(prhs[3],sequence_path,buflen1);

    int buflen2=(mxGetM(prhs[4])*mxGetN(prhs[4]))+1;
    sequence_name= (char *)mxCalloc(buflen2,sizeof(char));   
    status2=mxGetString(prhs[4],sequence_name,buflen2);


    int buflen3=(mxGetM(prhs[5])*mxGetN(prhs[5]))+1;
     output_path= (char *)mxCalloc(buflen3,sizeof(char));      
     status3=mxGetString(prhs[5],output_path,buflen3);
         if(status3!=0)
    mexWarnMsgTxt("Not enough space. String is truncated.");

    float x=(float)mxGetScalar(prhs[6]);
    float y=(float)mxGetScalar(prhs[7]);
    float width=(float)mxGetScalar(prhs[8]); 
    float height=(float)mxGetScalar(prhs[9]); 




     x_idx=mxGetPr(prhs[6]);
     y_idx=mxGetPr(prhs[7]);
     width_idx=mxGetPr(prhs[8]);
     height_idx=mxGetPr(prhs[9]);

     mexPrintf("the dimension is %f,%f,%f,%f\n",*x_idx,*y_idx,*width_idx,*height_idx);



    int N1=mxGetM(prhs[6])*mxGetN(prhs[6]);
    int N2=mxGetM(prhs[7])*mxGetN(prhs[7]);
    int N3=mxGetM(prhs[8])*mxGetN(prhs[8]);
    int N4=mxGetM(prhs[9])*mxGetN(prhs[9]);
    if(N1!=N2|N2!=N3|N3!=N4)
    mexErrMsgTxt("the dimension of the initial bounding box parameter is wrong");
    int NN=N1;

     plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(Max_track_number*5*NN,1,mxREAL);
     out_mat = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

     plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
     res = mxGetPr(plhs[1]);


 *res=struck_track(start_frame,end_frame,Max_track_number,sequence_path,sequence_name,output_path,out_mat,x_idx,y_idx,width_idx,height_idx,NN);

}
```

Is there some problems that may cause the exhaustion of memory?

Comment: You are allocating potentially large arrays, and in the JVM. Of course it's possible to run out of available memory. Emphasis on "available", it only matters if it's available to your process, it doesn't matter that you might have 16GB besides sitting free.

Comment: Do you mean that I should use mxDestroyArray to release memory after I use mxCreateDoubleMatrix？

Comment: That's the general rule, yeah.

Comment: But if I use mxDestroyArray, the output will not be passed to matlab, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use mxFree whenever using the following:

mxCalloc
mxMalloc
mxRealloc
mxArrayToString

I can see from your code that you are using mxCalloc but there is no corresponding mxFree for the same.

Comment: Thanks.struck_track is the original c++ function. Do I need to modify it to make sure all new variables are deleted? Will such memory allocated by c++ code be release automatically after mex file has been used?

Comment: I am not familiar with struck_track function. From what I understand by your usage, you do not need to explicitly free the variables viz. start_frame, end_frame, etc.

Comment: sorry by the confusion. I mean struck_track is an cpp code I want to utilize. Do I need to go inside the cpp code to make sure the memory is released manually? Or will the memory be released automatically?

Comment: Looking at start_frame variable. This is an variable you receive from matlab as input argument. These kind of variables inside mex file do not need to release manually. These are taken care automatically. Whereas variable such as sequence_path which use mxCalloc need to be released manually.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `mxFree` you can also increase the Java Heap Size. You can find it under settings, general, java heap memory.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know whether I need to modify the original c++ code to make sure the memory is released manually?